# Opening ssmssqlproj file in ssmse

Tags: ssms

i want to open the project file .ssmssqlproj in SQL server management studio 2008 express edition. While opening it gives the error that ssmssqlproj is not installed.
Is there any way through which i can open those ssmssqlproj files in ssmse.